# all classes which have a certain annotation and implement a certain interface

Tags: java, reflection

I am using [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to find certain classes in a multi module application.

I am able to find all classes which are implementing a certain interface:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");    
Set<Class<? extends MyInterface>> ddd = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);
```

I am able to find all classes which are having a certain annotation.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

However, i can't find a way to find all classes that are implementing that interface AND have the wanted annotation.

How can I combine these two approaches?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may retrieve both as you do actually.
Then keep the intersection of both by invoking the `Set.retainAll()` method  on one of two sets and pass the other as parameter.

> **boolean retainAll(Collection c);**
>
> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes
>   from this set all of its elements that are not contained in the
>   specified collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this
>   operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the
>   intersection of the two sets.

For example try it :

```
Reflections reflection = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Class<? extends MyInterface>> matchingClasses = reflection.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);    
Set<Class<?>> annotationClasses = reflection.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);

matchingClasses.retainAll(annotationClasses);
```

As result, `allClasses` will contain only `Class` instances that are present in the two Sets.

Comment: thank you very much! I wonder why you create a new Reflections instance twice. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @Dethrall You are welcome. No reason. It is a bad habit. I avoid declaring variable when it is not expensive to prevent side effect. I updated without.

Comment: I found two compiler errors: Firstline it should be Reflection**s** reflection.
And allClasses does not exist. There should be matchingClasses.
Just to prefect your answer ;)

Comment: @davidxxx A) it is not really a secret (any more now ;-) B) of course, it doesn't work instantly. I saw I had 130 yesterday evening - enough to get me online and start answering more questions. But when you want "results" soon, you cant wait for these accepts. So I simply tried to answer as quickly as possible yesterday. Lucky me, it worked out.

Comment: @davidxxx btw - here is the [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299217/how-to-create-a-list-of-all-questions-i-answered-without-accept) question with that SEDE query.

Comment: Glorfindel was not a joke so.  I though of the character in The Lord of the Rings :-) Thank you for the link. Interesting idea.

Comment: where does `allClasses`come from? Should it really be `matchingClasses`?

Answer (score 1):

You've already got two sets. Why not use them and do some set operations?

`ddd` has all the classes that implement `MyInterface`. `classes` has all the classes that are marked with `MyAnnotation`. And I want all the classes that satisfies both criteria. You should probably know what kind of set operation you need now - Intersection.

In Java `Set`s don't have `union`, `intersection` or `subtract` methods. To do an intersection you should call `retainAll`, so:

```
 ddd.retainAll(classes)
```

is what you need.